# Can SFSafariViewController load a POST request?

Tags: ios, post, sfsafariviewcontroller

I would like to load a POST request using SFSafariViewController, just like `webView.loadRequest(request)`. But I find `init(url:entersReaderIfAvailable:)` accepts NSURL only. Is it possible to do POST?

Comment: Why do you need to? Explain the situation you're in.

Comment: password autofill using WKWebView, like the way it works in safari or SFSafariViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that you can do the request in advance, but I guess you're doing it to get cookies or something like that..

So, untested, but you could create a local web page that you load with some parameters, it executes the POST using JavaScript and after its complete it redirects (if required) to some other URL.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. It's a browser not a webview.